# Visual-C Win32 API Layered Window Flickering

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I've been fiddling around with custom windows using the windows API. As of such I have been working with Extended Layered Windows. I have the window drawn, and it works. However when resizing the window there is an odd flickering/glitching [(Screenshot) ][1]when the redraw/UpdateLayeredWindow (and UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect) method is called. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

```
void redrawBaseWindow(HWND window) {
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(window, &rect);
    int elipseDiam = ((rect.right - rect.left)+(rect.bottom-rect.top))/2*0.025;
    HDC mainDC = GetDC(NULL);
    POINT destination = { rect.left,rect.top };
    POINT zero = destination;
    SIZE size = { rect.right - rect.left,rect.bottom - rect.top };
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.AlphaFormat = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 100));
    HBRUSH oldbrush = SelectObject(mainDC, brush);
    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HPEN oldPen = SelectObject(mainDC, pen);
    HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mainDC, size.cx,size.cy);
    HBITMAP oldBmp = SelectObject(mainDC, bmp);
    FillRect(mainDC, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
    Rectangle(mainDC, rect.left, rect.top + elipseDiam/2, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam/2);
    Rectangle(mainDC, rect.left + elipseDiam/2, rect.top, rect.right - elipseDiam/2, rect.bottom);
    UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO updated = { sizeof(UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO), NULL, &destination, &size, mainDC, &zero, RGB(0,0,0),&bf, ULW_COLORKEY, &rect};
    UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(window, &updated);
    //BOOL error = UpdateLayeredWindow(window, NULL, &destination, &size, mainDC, &zero, RGB(0, 0, 0), &bf, ULW_COLORKEY);
    SelectObject(mainDC, oldbrush);
    SelectObject(mainDC, oldBmp);
    SelectObject(mainDC, oldPen);
    DeleteObject(brush);
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    DeleteObject(pen);
}
```

Just in case, the Window Message Proc.

```
long __stdcall WndProc(HWND window, unsigned int msg, WPARAM wp, LPARAM lp) {
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    HDC hdc;
    TCHAR greeting[] = "Hello, World!";
    RECT rect_window;
    GetWindowRect(window, &rect_window);
    switch (msg) {
    case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        MessageBeep(MB_ICONERROR);
    case WM_CREATE:
    break;
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(0);
    break;
case WM_NCHITTEST:;
    int x = LOWORD(lp);
    int y = HIWORD(lp);
    if (x > rect_window.left && x<rect_window.right && y>rect_window.top && y < rect_window.top + 25)
        return HTCAPTION;
    if (x>=rect_window.left-3 && x<=rect_window.left+3) 
        return HTLEFT;
    if (x >= rect_window.right - 3 && x <= rect_window.right + 3)
        return HTRIGHT;
    if (y >= rect_window.top - 3 && y <= rect_window.top + 3)
        return HTTOP;
    if (y >= rect_window.bottom - 3 && y <= rect_window.bottom + 3)
        return HTBOTTOM;
    break;
case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    break;
case WM_SIZE:
    redrawBaseWindow(window);
    break;
case WM_PAINT:
    break;
}
return DefWindowProc(window, msg, wp, lp);
}
```

Edit:
[Gif of the glitch](https://gyazo.com/d8803962a7ae22f8b0660ca390bcbbc4)

Edit 2:
Using CreateCompatibleDC value into UpdateLayeredWindow [Also not working]

```
void redrawBaseWindow(HWND window) {
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(window, &rect);
    int elipseDiam = ((rect.right - rect.left)+(rect.bottom-rect.top))/2*0.025;
    HDC mainDC = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(mainDC);
    POINT destination = { rect.left,rect.top };
    POINT zero = destination;
    SIZE size = { rect.right - rect.left,rect.bottom - rect.top };
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.AlphaFormat = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 100));
    HBRUSH oldbrush = SelectObject(memDC, brush);
    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HPEN oldPen = SelectObject(memDC, pen);
    HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(memDC, size.cx,size.cy);
    HBITMAP oldBmp = SelectObject(memDC, bmp);
    FillRect(memDC, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
    Rectangle(memDC, rect.left, rect.top + elipseDiam/2, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam/2);
    Rectangle(memDC, rect.left + elipseDiam/2, rect.top, rect.right - elipseDiam/2, rect.bottom);
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.left + elipseDiam, rect.top + elipseDiam, rect.left, rect.top); //Top-Left
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.right - elipseDiam, rect.top, rect.right, rect.top + elipseDiam); //Top-Right
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.left + elipseDiam, rect.bottom - elipseDiam); //Bottom-Left
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.right - elipseDiam, rect.bottom, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam); //Bottom-Right
    UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO updated = { sizeof(UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO), NULL, &destination, &size, memDC, &zero, RGB(0,0,0),&bf, ULW_COLORKEY, &rect};
    UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(window, &updated);
    //BOOL error = UpdateLayeredWindow(window, NULL, &destination, &size, mainDC, &zero, RGB(0, 0, 0), &bf, ULW_COLORKEY);
    SelectObject(memDC, oldbrush);
    SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
    SelectObject(memDC, oldPen);
    DeleteObject(brush);
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    DeleteObject(pen);
    ReleaseDC(NULL,mainDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL,memDC);
}
```

Edit 3: DeleteDC on CreateCompatibleDC device, as well as creation of bitmap on screen DC rather than CompatibleDC

```
void redrawBaseWindow(HWND window) {
    RECT rect;
    GetWindowRect(window, &rect);
    int elipseDiam = ((rect.right - rect.left)+(rect.bottom-rect.top))/2*0.025;
    HDC mainDC = GetDC(NULL);
    HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(mainDC);
    POINT destination = { rect.left,rect.top };
    POINT zero = destination;
    SIZE size = { rect.right - rect.left,rect.bottom - rect.top };
    BLENDFUNCTION bf;
    bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
    bf.BlendFlags = 0;
    bf.AlphaFormat = 0;
    bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
    HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 100));
    HBRUSH oldbrush = SelectObject(memDC, brush);
    HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));
    HPEN oldPen = SelectObject(memDC, pen);
    HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mainDC, size.cx,size.cy);
    HBITMAP oldBmp = SelectObject(memDC, bmp);
    FillRect(memDC, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
    Rectangle(memDC, rect.left, rect.top + elipseDiam/2, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam/2);
    Rectangle(memDC, rect.left + elipseDiam/2, rect.top, rect.right - elipseDiam/2, rect.bottom);
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.left + elipseDiam, rect.top + elipseDiam, rect.left, rect.top); //Top-Left
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.right - elipseDiam, rect.top, rect.right, rect.top + elipseDiam); //Top-Right
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.left + elipseDiam, rect.bottom - elipseDiam); //Bottom-Left
    Ellipse(memDC, rect.right - elipseDiam, rect.bottom, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam); //Bottom-Right
    UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO updated = { sizeof(UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO), NULL, &destination, &size, memDC, &zero, RGB(0,0,0),&bf, ULW_COLORKEY, &rect};
    UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(window, &updated);
    //BOOL error = UpdateLayeredWindow(window, NULL, &destination, &size, mainDC, &zero, RGB(0, 0, 0), &bf, ULW_COLORKEY);
    SelectObject(memDC, oldbrush);
    SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
    SelectObject(memDC, oldPen);
    DeleteObject(brush);
    DeleteObject(bmp);
    DeleteObject(pen);
    DeleteDC(memDC);
    ReleaseDC(NULL,mainDC);
}
```

Original flickering fixed. Thanks [Jonathan Pottar]
Another error has occurred however : [This](https://gyazo.com/05e50f44e829b6f4207a2ed7340b5f18)

Comment: Please create an animated gif screenshot, I can't see the problem on your image.

Comment: Will do, just a moment

Comment: Selecting a different bitmap into a DC obtained from `GetDC` is a bit odd, and I'm not sure if passing the screen's DC to `UpdateLayeredWindow` is supported either. The normal usage is to select your bitmap into a memory DC obtained from `CreateCompatibleDC`, render into it and update the window from that. You also have a GDI resource leak (not calling `ReleaseDC`).

Comment: Thank you for noticing the GDI resource leak. Surprised I didn't notice it. I'm going to post an edit, I have tried using the CompatibleDC in the UpdateLayeredWindow, as it's specified, but it just did not want to work. I will post the edited code above. Note, it still does not work,

Comment: When a memory DC is created it has a monochrome bitmap in it, so if you call `CreateCompatibleBitmap` on that you also end up with a monochome bitmap. You need a bitmap compatible with the screen's DC. Also DCs obtained from `CreateCompatibleDC` are freed with `DeleteDC`, not `ReleaseDC`.

Comment: Thank you very much, if you can't tell I am fairly new to the Windows API. Or at least this portion of it. Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: Okay. After those fixes, while the window now renders again. The changes from resizing the window do not occur. I will show in an edit.

Comment: Okay. I realized my issue in using UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect, it is all working now.  Thank you for the clarification [Johnathan Potter](http://stackoverflow.com/users/506413/jonathan-potter) I com from  Linux/X11 development. So this is quite odd to me.

Comment: Please don't edit the answer into your question. Post an answer instead (see [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). If you have a new question, click the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button.

Answer (score 0):

```
void redrawBaseWindow(HWND window) {
RECT rect;
GetWindowRect(window, &rect);
int elipseDiam = ((rect.right - rect.left)+(rect.bottom-rect.top))/2*0.025;
HDC mainDC = GetDC(NULL);
HDC memDC = CreateCompatibleDC(mainDC);
POINT destination = { rect.left,rect.top };
POINT zero = destination;
SIZE size = { rect.right - rect.left,rect.bottom - rect.top };
BLENDFUNCTION bf;
bf.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
bf.BlendFlags = 0;
bf.AlphaFormat = 0;
bf.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
HBRUSH brush = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(255, 0, 100));
HBRUSH oldbrush = SelectObject(memDC, brush);
HPEN pen = CreatePen(PS_NULL, 0, RGB(0, 0, 0));
HPEN oldPen = SelectObject(memDC, pen);
HBITMAP bmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(mainDC, size.cx,size.cy);
HBITMAP oldBmp = SelectObject(memDC, bmp);
FillRect(memDC, &rect, CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0, 0, 0)));
Rectangle(memDC, rect.left, rect.top + elipseDiam/2, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam/2);
Rectangle(memDC, rect.left + elipseDiam/2, rect.top, rect.right - elipseDiam/2, rect.bottom);
Ellipse(memDC, rect.left + elipseDiam, rect.top + elipseDiam, rect.left, rect.top); //Top-Left
Ellipse(memDC, rect.right - elipseDiam, rect.top, rect.right, rect.top + elipseDiam); //Top-Right
Ellipse(memDC, rect.left, rect.bottom, rect.left + elipseDiam, rect.bottom - elipseDiam); //Bottom-Left
Ellipse(memDC, rect.right - elipseDiam, rect.bottom, rect.right, rect.bottom - elipseDiam); //Bottom-Right
UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO updated = { sizeof(UPDATELAYEREDWINDOWINFO), NULL, &destination, &size, memDC, &zero, RGB(0,0,0),&bf, ULW_COLORKEY, &rect};
UpdateLayeredWindowIndirect(window, &updated);
//BOOL error = UpdateLayeredWindow(window, NULL, &destination, &size, mainDC, &zero, RGB(0, 0, 0), &bf, ULW_COLORKEY);
SelectObject(memDC, oldbrush);
SelectObject(memDC, oldBmp);
SelectObject(memDC, oldPen);
DeleteObject(brush);
DeleteObject(bmp);
DeleteObject(pen);
DeleteDC(memDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL,mainDC);
}
```

This thankfully fixed my issue.